# What exactly is electric potential?

Tags: electricity, potential, potential-energy, voltage

My book says:

> When a small positive test charge is placed in the electric field due to another charge, it experiences a force. So work has to be done on the positive test charge to move it against this force of repulsion. The electric potential at a point in an electric field is defined as the amount of work done in bringing a unit positive charge from infinity to that point without acceleration.

I have several questions about this:

1. What is a "test charge"?
2. "Work has to be done on the positive test charge to move it against this force of repulsion", but what if the charge in the electric field is negative?
3. Work done = Fs
   Since we are moving the charge from infinity to a point in the electric field, s = infinity. So, work done = infinity, which would imply that electric potential is always infinity. This is clearly not the case, so what exactly am I missing here?

I'd appreciate if the answer is more theoretical than mathematical, since I haven't studied advanced mathematics.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is voltage?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/203389/)

Comment: A nice way to think about potential is that potential energy between two charges is $qq'/r²$ (nevermind the constants), but this relation is not fundamental to the charge (q) in the sense that it contains a term of q', in other words this expression is not something intrinsic to the charge, however if we remove q' from  the expression and get $q/r²$, then this expression is intrinsic to the particle and cannot be changed by the change of external charge whereas potential energy changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A test charge is a charge with a magnitude so small that placing it at a point has a negligible affect on the field around the point.
2. If the test charge would be negative then the work done would have the opposite sign, but the same magnitude as in the positive test charge case
3. Work done = F s only applies to constant forces, the correct equation is $\text{work} = \int \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{s}$

Comment: 3. I am not sure what the formula you said means. How exactly does it change the question?

Comment: @AryanKataria The formula above is an integral (a line integral technically), which means instead of multiplying the full-distance-traveled by a fixed force $W=Fs$, you multiply each incremental distance $ds$ by the force at that location, $F(s) ds$; then you sum (hence the S shape in the integral) all those contributions. (The quantities are also vectors.) The key point is that electric force is not constant as you move, unlike e.g. gravity when you're really close to the Earth's surface (gravity is approximately constant near the Earth's surface). The correct output is finite, not infinite.

Comment: @AryanKataria with no math at all, let's imagine you're moving the charge from the infinity with your hand, and place it where you need. When you're very far, the charge you're holding with you approximately doesn't feel any influence from the regions of space where you will place it, so you're doing approximately zero work to move that charge closer to the region of interest, i.e. the region of space with the charges that produces the electic field. As you move closer to that region, you start feeling a force on the charge and you have to apply on it an opposite force, doing work

Comment: The overall work done is finite, even if your path is infinitely long, because when you're far away you're doing no net work, while you have to do some effort to move the charge only when you're approaching the already existent charges, where the electric field they're producing is not negligible. The meaning of the integral is the sum of the work you do for every step you take along your path. Even if you take an infinte number of steps along an infinite path, you do some "sensible" work only on a finite number of steps close enough to the regions where charges are, qualitatively speaking

Comment: @basics so, we have to calculate the work done when the charge is outside the electric field, and the work done to place the charge at a certain position inside the electric field separately, and then add them? 
I suppose the force applied when the charge is outside the electric field would be zero as we have to first apply a very low force to move the charge, then zero force to maintain its velocity, and then a very low negative force to stop it just outside the electric field. Then, why do we take the initial position of charge as infinity instead of any point outside the electric field?

Comment: There is no inside or outside the field, since a field is defined as nothing more that a function of space coordinates. Usually, there are regions of space where the electric field is more or less intense, at the limit with zero intensity (the regions that you call "outside the field"). Far away from the charges generating the field, the intensity of the field is very small, approximately zero, so you do approximately zero work when you move the charge. If you have a limited region where the electric field is different from zero, you can thinking at start moving the charges just outside it

Answer (score 0):

One intuitive interpretation of electric potential is that it's the work the electric field at a point in space does per unit charge. This can be seen by observing that:

$$V = \int{E\cdot ds}= \int{\frac{F}{q} \cdot ds} = \frac{W}{q}$$

Where $V$ is electric potential, $E$ is electric field, $F$ is the force due to Coulomb's law on a charge of arbitrary magnitude $q$, and $ds$ is some infinitesimal segment. In other words, the electric potential is defined to be almost the same as the work done on a charge by an electric field, but divided by all the charge. Hence, it is the work done by an electric field per unit charge.

This equation is different from the one you have in your question. Let's say you're bringing a charge in from $\infty \rightarrow a$. Our integral equation $V = \int{E\cdot ds}$ tells us to :

1. Imagine a path from $\infty 
   \rightarrow a$. Now the explicit path turns out not to matter here, only that you start and end at the two boundary points ($\infty$ and $a$). [Btw, this is because the electric field is conservative, i.e., its curl is 0].
2. Now at each very very small segment (infinitesimally small) in the path, find the electric field.
3. Take the dot product between the infinitesimally small "path" ($ds$) and the electric field at every single point along the path. Sum all of these contributions up. You're done.

This computation is much more general that what you provided in your question. The formula you are using assumes that the $E$ is uniform everywhere along the path.

Aside:

Also, multivariable calculus is pretty integral (pun intended) for studying electricity and magnetism. It is a majority of the language used to formulate E&M in undergraduate and above textbooks.

I'm not sure what level you're at/textbook you are using. But, it is better to start familiarizing oneself with calculus earlier than later. It takes a while (I think) to get a good grasp of using it.

Comment: I guess that he needs more qualitative explanation, since he hasn't studied advanced math yet (I don't know exactly what he exactly means with "advanced", but I'd rather keep it simple)

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found to visualize voltage i.e. electric potential is as height/elevation. You can picture charges and current as marbles rolling  or as water flowing. Positive charges and current flow from high voltage to low voltage, exactly like marbles or water do under gravity.  Negative charges and currents flow from low to high voltage, as if under anti-gravity.

Any voltage diagram is telling you a topological map of how charges will flow in that region.

This analogy is a mathematically accurate one, because elevation itself is simply gravitational potential, telling us how masses move.